# Algorithm to find all possible arrays of max size L that sum up to N or less

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I want to find all possible arrays -of non-negative numbers- that sum up to -at most- N in JavaScript:

```
function findArrays(maxSize, maxSum){}
```

**Example input:** `findArrays(3, 10)`

**Some acceptable outputs:** (not writing all as it would be too long)

```
[[0], [0,0,0], [10,0,0], [1,9], [1,2,3] /*, ... */]
```

**What I tried so far:**

I know it looks like homework but it's not :) I can think of a solution that simply generates all (`size*maxSum`) possible arrays of acceptable sizes and then iterate through them to check if sum is greater than `maxSum`. However, I think this solution is very bad in terms of performance as `maxSum` gets bigger. I'm looking for a more efficient implementation but I just don't know where to start.

**My "bad" solution**

```
function getNextArray(r,maxVal){
    for(var i=r.length-1;i>=0;i--){
        if(r[i]<maxVal){
            r[i]++;
            if(i<r.length-1){
                r[i+1]=0;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return r;
}

function getAllArraysOfSize(size, maxVal){
    var arrays=[],r=[],i;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){
        r[i]=0;
    }
    while(r.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) < (maxVal*size)){
        r = getNextArray(r.slice(),maxVal);
        arrays.push(r);
    }
    return arrays;
};

function findArrays(maxSize, maxSum){
    var allArrays=[],arraysOfFixedSize=[],acceptableArrays=[],i,j;
    for(i=1; i<=maxSize; i++){
        arraysOfFixedSize=getAllArraysOfSize(i,maxSum);
        for(j=0; j<arraysOfFixedSize.length; j++){
            allArrays.push(arraysOfFixedSize[j]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i<allArrays.length; i++){
        if(allArrays[i].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) <= maxSum){
            acceptableArrays.push(allArrays[i]);
        }
    }
    return acceptableArrays;
};
```

Comment: please add your code.

Comment: Added the code for my current solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursion and a generator. The number of outputs grows quickly for higher valued arguments, so I keep them low here:

```js
function * findArrays(maxSize, maxSum) {
  let arr = [];
  
  function * recur(maxSum) {
    let k = arr.length;
    yield [...arr]; // or: if (k) yield [...arr]
    if (k === maxSize) return;
    for (let i = 0; i <= maxSum; i++) {
      arr[k] = i;
      yield * recur(maxSum - i);
    }
    arr.length = k;
  }
  
  yield * recur(maxSum);  
}

// demo
for (let arr of findArrays(2, 4))
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

NB: this also produces the empty array, which makes sense. If you want to avoid this, then just check that you don't yield an empty array.

If you prefer working with plain functions instead of generators, then translate the innermost `yield` expression to a `push` unto a `result` array, as follows:

```js
function findArrays(maxSize, maxSum) {
  let arr = [];
  let result = []; // <--- will collect all the subarrays
 
  function recur(maxSum) {
    let k = arr.length;
    result.push([...arr]);
    if (k === maxSize) return;
    for (let i = 0; i <= maxSum; i++) {
      arr[k] = i;
      recur(maxSum - i);
    }
    arr.length = k;
  }
  
  recur(maxSum);
  return result;
}

// demo
for (let arr of findArrays(2, 4))
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Comment: Thank you! I will need some post-processing anyway (as all zeros is also unacceptable for me) so empty arrays are not a problem. However, this function returns arrays that sum up to `maxSize`, not `maxSum`. Do you have a typo somewhere?

Comment: Indeed, initial call of `recur` had an argument that should not be there. Corrected.

Comment: it works now! Also I love how it gives all the empty and all-zeroes answers in the beginning, will be easy to post-process. I would appreciate some explanation on how it is more efficient than my solution, as I don't understand how the generator works. But this answers my question so I'm accepting it. Thanks!

Comment: I added an equivalent non-generator version to the answer. I didn't look at your code in depth, but one thing that makes it less efficient is that it keeps calculating the sum of the subarrays, while it is more efficient to just pass an argument that indicates how much value there is still left to potentially *add* to the array without crossing the limit.

Comment: Good point, thanks. Also my code fills the heap memory too quickly as it creates more than necessary arrays. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

i hope this is helpful

```
const data = [[0],[0,0,0],[10,0,0],[1,9],[1,2,3]];

function findArrays(maxSize, maxSum){
  return data.reduce(
    (acc, value) => {
      if (value.length <= maxSize) {
        const tempValue = value;
        const sum = tempValue.reduce((acc, val) => val >= 0 ? acc + val : 0, 0);
        if (sum <= maxSum && sum > 0) acc.push(value);
      }
      return acc
    }, []
  )
}

console.log(findArrays(3, 10));
```