# Algorithm to find all possible arrays of size L that sum up to N or less

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I want to find all possible arrays -of non-negative integers- of size `L` that sum up to -at most- `N` in JavaScript:

```
function findArrays(size, maxSum){}
```

**Example input:** `findArrays(3, 2)`

**Example output:**

```
[[0,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,0,2], [0,1,0], [0,1,1], [0,2,0], [1,0,0], [1,0,1], [1,1,0], [2,0,0]]
```

**What I tried:**

I came up with this algorithm:

- Starting from left, add the array members
- If the sum is equal to `N` at slot `i`:

  - If the member at the current index is equal to `N`, reset all the indices up to here and increment the next slot
  - Otherwise: reset previous slots and increment this slot
- Otherwise:

  - Increment the first available slot

**My code:**

```
let getNextArray = (r,L,N)=>{
    let sum=0, ind=0, i;
    for(i=0; i<L; i++){
        sum += r[i];
        if(sum===N){
            ind = i + (r[i]===N?1:0);
            break;
        }
    }
    r[ind]++;
    for(i=0; i<ind; i++){
        r[i]=0;
    }
    return r;
};

let findArrays=(L, N)=>{
    let arrays=[],r=[],i;
    for(i=0; i<L; i++){
        r[i] = 0;
    }
    while(r[L-1]<N){
        r = getNextArray(r,L,N);
        arrays.push(r.slice());
    }
    return arrays;
}
```

It works for my example input, but when I call it with `findArrays(5,3)` it finds half (28 / 56) of the answers. Even if I made it work, I doubt it would be efficient for bigger inputs as it calculates the sum for each turn. I'm sure there is a more clever way to do it which I can't find..

Yesterday I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63983520/algorithm-to-find-all-possible-arrays-of-max-size-l-that-sum-up-to-n-or-less) which had a very good answer in terms of efficiency, but I realized I need fixed sized arrays. Apologies for the similar question but maybe it will help someone else one day :)

I could also use a method `findArrays(size, sum)` and iterate it with sums `1:N`, unfortunately I don't know how to do that either.

Comment: I just solved it by starting at [0,0,0]. Loop over first index and fill in the numbers. [0,0,0], [1,0,0], [2,0,0]. Then I start on the second index. I loop over all the array just generated and see what I can add to that to get to the max. So [0,0,0] would be [0,1,0], [0,2,0] and move to next [1,1,0]  and nothing can be done with [2,] so now move to next index and loop over all the arrays we had.....[0,0,1], [0,0,2], [1,0,1],[0,1,1], [0,0, 2]

Comment: Yup, that looks like what I had in mind. But it gets trickier when size is more than three.

Comment: Short version: `function* f(l, m){ if (l === 0) { yield []; return; } for (let head = 0; head <= m; head++) for (let tail of f(l - 1, m - head)) yield [head, ...tail]; } const findArrays = (l, m) => [...f(l, m)];` - if you want more performance, you need to do the iteration manually, and set array elements, instead of concatenating. I wrote one, but it doesn't fit in a comment. Also, the answer provided doesn't appear all that slow tbh.

Comment: Thanks! Why not post an answer? :) Looks like it's working, no idea about efficiency. For the current answer, I don't know, maybe it's good enough. I intend to call this function with big numbers (size more than 10 and sum more than 100) which already causes memory allocation problems, so I'm looking for a minimalistic solution.

Comment: Guess it does fit in a comment... `const findArrays = (l, m) => {
  let result = [], current = Array(l).fill(0);
  const f = (l, m, d) => {
    if (l === 0) result.push(current.slice());
    else for (let i = 0; i <= m; i++) {
      current[d] = i;
      f(l - 1, m - i, d + 1);
    }
  }
  f(l, m, 0);
  return result;
}` too lazy to optimize this further.

Comment: Here is another funny version (avoids function calls). I wrote it to port to webassembly, but it's kind of late here, so i didn't finish. As javascript, it's not all too useful.

Comment: `const findArrays = (ol, m) => { const l = ol - 1; let result = []; let current = Array(ol).fill(0); let numbers = Array(l).fill(0); let maxima = Array(ol).fill(m + 1); let d = 0; while (true) { if (d === l) { for (let u = 0; u < maxima[d]; u++) { current[d] = u; result[result.length] = current.slice(); } d--; if (d < 0) break; } else { current[d] = numbers[d]; if (numbers[d] === maxima[d]) { numbers[d] = 0; d--; if (d < 0) break; } else { maxima[d + 1] = maxima[d] - numbers[d]; numbers[d]++; d++; } continue; } } return result;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify [trincot's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63983676/10221765) with a small `filter` at the end:

```js
function findArrays(maxSize, maxSum) {
  let arr = [];
  let result = []; // <--- will collect all the subarrays

  function recur(maxSum) {
    let k = arr.length;
    result.push([...arr]);
    if (k === maxSize) return;
    for (let i = 0; i <= maxSum; i++) {
      arr[k] = i;
      recur(maxSum - i);
    }
    arr.length = k;
  }

  recur(maxSum);
  return result.filter(({ length }) => length == maxSize);
}

// demo
for (let arr of findArrays(3, 2))
  console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Comment: Indeed that's another solution, but I think it wouldn't be that efficient in that case, as it is generating more arrays than necessary. Also I think the `filter()` alone can be costly for big `result`s. I would appreciate a solution that generates no more than the necessary number of arrays. Thanks for your help though, +1

Comment: I did speed tests with bigger inputs and yours is the fastest one. Accepting your answer. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non-yielding version of a recursive function which will give the results you want. It figures out all possible values at the current level (`0..maxSum`) and then appends them to all possible results for arrays with `size-1`:

```js
const findArrays = (size, maxSum) => {
  let possibles = Array.from({
    length: maxSum + 1
  }, (_, i) => i);
  if (size == 1) return possibles;
  let result = [];
  possibles.forEach(p => {
    findArrays(size - 1, maxSum - p).forEach(a => {
      result.push([p].concat(a));
    });
  });
  return result;
}

console.log(findArrays(3, 2));
```

Comment: Thanks! Many good answers, don't know which one to accept. +1'ing everyone. I think I will need to measure execution times with big numbers to see which one is faster.

Comment: @wololoo no worries - I'm glad this was helpful. Note it might be faster for this to replace `result.push([p].concat(a))` with `result.push([p, ...a])` - I'm not sure which would be more efficient.